# How are 専攻 and 専門 different?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

What is the difference between 専門 *senmon* and 専攻 *senkō*?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40465/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've seen so far, 専門 is used to refer to specialties within trades/crafts, e.g. specialist cheese cake bakery.

専攻 is what someone studies as their "major" in e.g. a university.

Comment: Someone should pass this note along to some of the JP textbook publishers, as many use 専門 to mean major. It isn't entirely wrong, but was surprised to hear 専攻 from other people for the first time before I knew of this.